# Does a Mule manual shutdown allow the current flow to complete?

Tags: mule

I'm running a flow on mule-standalone-3.5.0 on Linux and trying to understand what happens in the case of a manual server shutdown.

Right now I see the currently running 'main' flow which is a recursive loop continuing during the shutdown, long enough to finish processing of the current message. I would like to know if that is part of 'graceful shutdown' or just good luck.

It does try to call itself again which I stop by checking the run state of a flow I know stops quickly.

```
def flow = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct("initFlow")

if ((flow.isStopped() || flow.isStopping())) {
     message.setInvocationProperty('runState', 'stopping')
}
else {
     message.setInvocationProperty('runState', 'running')   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever Mule receives the shutdown signal, it makes sure to finish processing the current message to avoid loss of data and then starts closing down all endpoints and flows, together with thread pool cleanups. HTH.

Comment: might be another question.  Upon receipt of the shutdown signal how does Mule know it has finish processing the current message?

Comment: I have no idea how Mule does it, so it would be ideal to open another thread, but I would assume that Mule keeps track of the message somewhere on the memory.

Comment: One easy way of Mule figuring out it has processed every message is to check the amount of threads in each threadpool. If the amount of threads in the pool is equal to the amount with which it started, that means no messages are currently being processed.